How is MustVerifyEmail a trait and is being implemented not used
Sorry if my question is repetitive but I couldn't find the exact answer to my question.
In PHP, a trait can only be implemented with the keyword use, and an interface can only be implemented with the keyword implements.
In Laravel docs the MustVerifyEmail is called an interface and implemented with the keyword implements but actually in the source code it is a trait.
So my question is I cannot understand the concept used in Laravel because that scenario causes errors in native PHP, cannot implements a trait.
Thank you.

I'm not sure if I understand the question fully, sorry in advance. MustVerifyEmail is indeed an interface, but there is a trait with the same name, here is the link to the interface and here is the trait Laravel cannot change the behavior of the language I think you are just mistaken

Thank you for your reply, yes you got the question right and cleared my mistake. But this raised another question, how am I not forced to define the methods in that interface when I implement it?

Yes, normally you have to define them but in this case you mentioned (Auth related) you won't need to since the class extended Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User already uses the MustVerifyEmail trait, here is the code of the class. Hope this explains it, feel free to ask any more questions you have.

Thank you for your help. So to understand it clearly if I use a trait defining the same methods in the interface I am not forced to define those methods in the class implementing the interface?

Yes. Traits are like portable code basically! When you use them in a class, it is like defining the methods normally.

I get it now. Thank you very much for clearing the fog :)

Perhaps you can turn your comments into an answer @Mohammadsiabbou

Sure @geertjanknapen

MustVerifyEmail is indeed an interface. However, there is a trait with the same name, here is the link to the interface and here is the trait, Laravel cannot change the behavior of the language, the class still has to implement the required methods which in this case can be solved just by using the trait.
